# Stringstream Doesn't Include Initial Data

Tags: c++

My problem is really petty, but nevertheless I have not found any answer by asking google or by asking peers. The problem can be shown by the following code:

```
std::ostringstream oss("I am a ");
    oss << "donkey";
    std::cout << oss.str();
```

Expected Output: "I am a donkey"

Actual Output: "donkey"

What happens here? Is the initial string the stringstream had to begin with been discarded?

Comment: By default, an output stream is opened with mode `std::ios_base::open` which causes initial output supplied on construction to be discarded.    Add a second argument to the construction of `std::ios_base::app` (to append to the stream) or `std::ios_base::ate` (to position the stream pointer at the end).   A argument you supply will be bitwise-or-ed with `std::ios_base::open` anyway, but you can make that explicit by using `std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::open`  or  `std::ios_base::ate | std::ios_base::open`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `std::ios_base::ate` to the constructor, otherwise it would overwrite from the beginning:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    std::ostringstream oss("I am a ", std::ios_base::ate);
    oss << "donkey";
    std::cout << oss.str();
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/IIfOkB

More information: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream

Example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str